# Как в jquery стилизовать элемент родителя при его фокусе и вернуть прежние стили при выходе из фокуса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть элемент, мне нужно чтобы при его фокусе у родителя менялся background-color и после того как фокус перейдет на следующий элемент, вернуть родителю прежнее значение background-color.
У меня получилось только назначить нужный background-color, но как вернуть прежнее значение я не знаю. Можете подсказать?

```
$(".child").focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'grey')
}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого jQuery есть [focusout()](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

```
// Фокус
$(".child").focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'grey')
}
);
// Выход из фокуса
$(".child").focusout(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'white')
}
);
```

Comment: для этого есть `.child:focus { background-color: grey; }` а не вот это вот

Comment: @teran Так суть вопроса в том, чтобы сделать это с помощью jQuery

Comment: если хирург вас оперировать ложкой начнет, вы ему тоже предложите ее заточить, а не скальпель взять?

Comment: @teran не соглашусь с вами, в вашем примере меняется стиль ребёнка, а не родителя, но несомненно можно просто написать селектор родителя и да, css также по моему мнению будет лучше и быстрее.

Comment: @Artemka1806 а что-то я про родителя пропустил, пардон.